# EaselJS adds Bitmap to stage oversized

Tags: easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to dynamically create and add a Bitmap image and add it to stage, but when I do the image always comes in incredibly oversized (2-3x), so I always have to find some arbitrary scale numbers to get it right (ex 375x500 image made me use scale of scaleX:.8 scaleY:.33), and even then it comes out crappy and tiled. I even tried messing around with the canvas size, and it's lack of proper scale scales with the allotted space :x

The code I'm using is essentially this:

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap("images/img.jpg");
stage.addChild(bmp);
stage.update();
```

What do I need to set to make the image show up like I intend it to?

Comment: Are you sizing your canvas with css? Sounds like your canvas might be stretched out.

Comment: +1 for @Andrew's response. If you scale a canvas with CSS, it will stretch. Use JavaScript to set the pixel dimensions of the canvas instead.